# Cannot loggin twice in ssh if DNS tunnel is active

Tags: server, ssh, dns, vpn, wireguard

I recently installed WireGuard so I can tunnel DNS request to the VPN.
I also have portsentry and fail2ban but now I disabled them until I find the solution to the problem.

When I login into my user in ssh, everything is ok. But I have to wait several minutes before the second login, even if I close the first connection, if not it tries a long time to connect but the connection is timed out. I have this problem only on wan, not on lan.
In other device (a smartphone) I can check that if I disable the VPN I can login several times without problems.
But what is really weird is that in my pc, even if I disable the VPN I have the same problem (and DNS without VPN are 8.8.8.8 and 9.9.9.9).

In `/var/log/auth.log` I could see the warning `"POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!"` pointing to my IP. So, it must be a DNS reverse advice.
I disabled these warnings adding `UseDNS no` to the system's `sshd_config` file.
I still have this second login problem even now.

Some other information:

- iptables is not banning my IP and after a `iptables -X` and `iptables -F` I have the same problem.
- The IP is not in the `/etc/hosts.deny` file.

My `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` is:

```
# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port "myport"
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#Privilege Separation is turned on for security
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 1024

# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin no
StrictModes yes

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile  %h/.ssh/authorized_keys

# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
IgnoreRhosts yes
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh_known_hosts
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
HostbasedAuthentication no
# Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes

# To enable empty passwords, change to yes (NOT RECOMMENDED)
PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes

# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
PasswordAuthentication yes

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication yes
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no

#MaxStartups 10:30:60
#Banner /etc/issue.net

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes

# Only allow "myuser"
AllowUsers "myuser"

# Allow DNS reverse (wireguard)
UseDNS no
```

where "myport" and "myuser" are my port and user data.

How can I check what is wrong?